# Get string between words, and one word is optional

Tags: php, regex

I have a lot of strings like this:

```
"Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11440 Horario de atención: 08:01 a 21:00 hs"
"Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11441 Horario de atención: 08:02 a 21:00 hs"
"Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11442 Horario de atención: 08:03 a 21:00 hs"
"Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11443 Horario de atención: 08:04 a 21:00 hs"
"Dirección: xxxxx Horario de atención: 08:05 a 21:00 hs"
```

The first problem: I need to get the text that is where the "xxxxx" are placed. It can be one word and maybe more, its an address.

The second problem: the text after the address is optional, so I can have something like this

```
"Dirección: CALLE 137 E/ 32 Y 32BIS"
```

How can I get the address from my strings?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex with [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and a non-capturing group to match on the end of the line where the optional text after the address is not present; e.g:

```php
$strings = <<<EOF
Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11440 Horario de atención: 08:01 a 21:00 hs
Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11441 Horario de atención: 08:02 a 21:00 hs
Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11442 Horario de atención: 08:03 a 21:00 hs
Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11443 Horario de atención: 08:04 a 21:00 hs
Dirección: xxxxx Horario de atención: 08:05 a 21:00 hs
Dirección: CALLE 137 E/ 32 Y 32BIS
EOF;

$regex = '/(?<=Dirección:\s).*(?:(?=Horario de atención)|$)/';
preg_match_all($regex, $strings, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => AV. RIVADAVIA 11440 
            [1] => AV. RIVADAVIA 11441 
            [2] => AV. RIVADAVIA 11442 
            [3] => AV. RIVADAVIA 11443 
            [4] => xxxxx 
            [5] => CALLE 137 E/ 32 Y 32BIS
        )
)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This RegEx cannot fulfill the requirement of second problem.

Comment: @SeaBean Updated. This should now meet the second requirement.

Comment: That's great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) to obtain what you need:

```
Dirección:\s*((?:(?!Horario de atención:).)*)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oB4gW8/2), the result is in Group 1:

```
$re = '~Dirección:\s*((?:(?!Horario de atención:).)*)~u'; 
$str = "Dirección: CALLE 137 E/ 32 Y 32BIS\nDirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11440 Horario de atención: 08:01 a 21:00 hs"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/PwSznL).

The tempered greedy token `(?:(?!Horario de atención:).)*` matches anything but a symbol that is starting a substring `Horario de atención:`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example; you just need to look for the zipcode in the address as the limiter. For example

```
<?php

$strings = <<<EOF
Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11440 Horario de atención: 08:01 a 21:00 hs
Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11441 Horario de atención: 08:02 a 21:00 hs
Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11442 Horario de atención: 08:03 a 21:00 hs
Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11443 Horario de atención: 08:04 a 21:00 hs
Dirección: xxxxx Horario de atención: 08:05 a 21:00 hs
EOF;

preg_match_all('/Dirección:\s(.*\d{5})/', $strings, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Results in item #2 in the array to have the data you need:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11440
            [1] => Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11441
            [2] => Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11442
            [3] => Dirección: AV. RIVADAVIA 11443
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => AV. RIVADAVIA 11440
            [1] => AV. RIVADAVIA 11441
            [2] => AV. RIVADAVIA 11442
            [3] => AV. RIVADAVIA 11443
        )

)
```